# Keeping a sprite with in the window Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

I have this sprite that is controlled with the arrow keys, but won't stay within the screens boundaries. For some reason, it only stops at the left end, but not the top, bottom, and right.

Here is what I have so far:

```
if self.rect.right == screen.get_rect().right:
    self.rect.right = self.rect.right - 10
if self.rect.left == screen.get_rect().left:
    self.rect.right = self.rect.right + 10
if self.rect.top == screen.get_rect().top:
    self.rect.top = self.rect.top - 10
if self.rect.bottom == screen.get_rect().bottom:
    self.rect.bottom = self.rect.bottom + 10
```

Answer (score 3):

It's most probably because you are comparing with `==`.  The coordinates increase by more than one at a time, so they might jump from below to over the limit and reach larger values.  Try:

```
if self.rect.right > screen.get_rect().right:
    self.rect.right = screen.get_rect().right
...
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `clamp_ip`, which moves the rect as long as it's inside the other rect